# archive.org Wayback Machine API multiple URLs at one Request

Tags: url, parameters, request

Is somebody aware of how to pass multiple urls in one request to the [Wayback Machine API](https://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php) ? Or is it even possible to do that?

I looked for it all over the internet but I didn't find anything about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

one url, one request, one answer - but a list of urls can be checked within the loop; for ex. in R:

```
urls <- c("http://onet.pl","http://wired.com","http://geocities.com")

ask_wm_api <- function(urls) {
  library(jsonlite)
  df <- data.frame()
  for(u in urls) {
    x <- fromJSON(paste0("http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=",u))
    df <- rbind(df, as.data.frame(x))
  }
  return(df)
}

r <- ask_wm_api(urls)
```

in effect: a data frame which can be easily export to csv:

[image: in effect: a data frame which can be easily export to csv]

or passed in R:

```
r$archived_snapshots.closest.url
[1] http://web.archive.org/web/20180511050915/https://www.onet.pl/  
[2] http://web.archive.org/web/20180510143400/https://www.wired.com/
[3] http://web.archive.org/web/20180511013018/http://@geocities.com/
3 Levels: http://web.archive.org/web/20180511050915/https://www.onet.pl/ ...
```

Want more data? Try to use [Wayback CDX Server API](https://github.com/internetarchive/wayback/tree/master/wayback-cdx-server)