# How do I use a dataframe column instead of a copy-pasting urls in this loop function?

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe with one column (df$urls) having 50 rows of urls. How do I reproduce the [code below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50287858/10404767) using the 50rows I have in the df$urls instead of copy pasting then individually?

```
urls <- c("http://onet.pl","http://wired.com","http://geocities.com")

ask_wm_api <- function(urls) {
  library(jsonlite)
  df <- data.frame()
  for(u in urls) {
    x <- fromJSON(paste0("http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=",u))
    df <- rbind(df, as.data.frame(x))
  }
  return(df)
}

r <- ask_wm_api(urls)
```

Comment: You can just do `ask_wm_api(as.character(df$urls))`

Comment: Thank you for the super fast response. This is better, though I got this response: 

```Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1```

Comment: That is a different issue related to not fetching any values in one of the loop.  You can wrap with `tryCatch` and and do the `rbind` at the end after filtering i.e. keept it in a list.  `lst1 <- lapply(urls, function(u)  as.data.frame(fromJSON(paste0("http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=",u)))`

Comment: Thank you. Answer accepted since it worked on a different df.

Comment: @akrun -- introducing `tryCatch` and `error = function(){NA}` messed the whole thing for me. 
Do you mind expanding your comment to the whole chunk, if possible. I can then study how you did it slowly.

Comment: I would use `lst1 <- lapply(urls, function(u) fromJSON(paste0("http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=",u)) );do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, as.data.frame))`. If the `list` element is NULL, it will be dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column is `factor` convert to `character` with `as.character` and pass it as a vector

```
ask_wm_api(as.character(df$urls))
```

i.e. `df$urls` will be of same structure as the `urls` created by typing one a time